# SkImageDecoder::factory returned null

Tags: android, android-imageview

i am trying to display an image from net..and i am using ignition library for RemoteImageView..
this is the code..

```
public class images extends Activity{
public String a,b,c,d;
public java.lang.String url;
RemoteImageView iv;
Bitmap bitmap;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    a= getIntent().getExtras().getString("s1");
    b = getIntent().getExtras().getString("s2");
    c = getIntent().getExtras().getString("s3");
    d = getIntent().getExtras().getString("s4");

    setContentView(R.layout.ignition);


     iv=(RemoteImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
}

public void p(View v) throws MalformedURLException{
    String u="http://www.infrabazaar.com/"+a;//<--------(1)
    iv.setImageUrl(u);
    iv.loadImage();
}}
```

the images should be displayed based on the info sent from the previous class...
if i give a complete link of the image like "http://www.infrabazaar.com/machinary-client-images/1315201358_0.JPG"... iam able display that image on the screen.. but when i am passing the link as in line (1).. it is showing factory returned null message...can any one tell me what can resolve the problem?

Comment: Make sure your image exists on the server. I tried to open the image link you provided in browser and it says. "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: the line a= getIntent().getExtras().getString("s1"); can set a to null which would not throw an exception when appending a to string u. Check the value of u prior to calling iv.setImageUrl to ensure it is what you think it is.

Comment: Sorry!! it was a problem with the link itself....cleared the problem by getting correct link.. thnq for help.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This RemoteImageView solves much of the "Factory Returned null " problem... now i get very few times this error... but once i load other image and then try reloading the image for which i got the error it loads properly..