# All Images not loading in ImageView while using Ion Library in Android

Tags: android, android-ion

I am loading images from the server using `Ion` library. Some of my images load while some don't load. i am getting a message as follows:

```
 SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

I have referred to the following questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470507/how-to-solve-the-skimagedecoderfactory-returned-null) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006785/android-skimagedecoder-factory-returned-null).

Can anyone help me to fix this error and load the Image using Ion.

Comment: Did you try any other library to load all image...?

Comment: Yes, I tried with picasso and same error

Comment: Are you sure the server and or those images are OK?

Comment: Yes I ahve checked... its showing correctly on Web

Answer (score 0):

please check your image url if your image url contain space so you want to remove that extra space and after try to load that image url.
example :
   imageurl=imageurl.replace(" ","%20");